# Call an async function from within a blocking chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest handler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension which has an `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` handler, with `["requestBody", "blocking"]` params.

I want to call an async function inside the background script from within this handler.

Currently I use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to pass a message to the content script which then receives it and sends a message to the background using `chrome.extension.sendMessage`, which receives it and calls the said async function.

Both the background & content script are using `chrome.runtime.onMessage` to listen to those messages.

This feels like a pretty messy workaround - I guess I don't need the content script to act as proxy.
Can I trigger an async function from within the `onBeforeRequest` handler directly?

Comment: And what's wrong with just calling the function directly?

Comment: @vanowm Since the handler is blocking, I can't call an async function inside it. I know I can call it without `await` to trigger it, but then I can't wait for its response

Comment: It's not possible in Chrome, but depending on what exactly you're doing currently a solution might exist, so you need to show your code.